# Dialogflow loses context unexplainably

Tags: dialogflow-es

I don't understand what happens with my bot, at some point during the conversation it loses some context variables.

In the following screenshot, you can see that the variables `school` and `campus` are empty. That's weird because the reply the bot does is

> Voici les bourses disponibles pour `IDRAC` `Paris`

Where `IDRAC` is the `school` variable, and `Paris` is the `campus`.
I don't understand how the bot can both display the proper value (set previously by different Intents), and not have the value set.

[image]

Here is the Diagnostic Info

```
{
  "responseId": "759621b6-58cc-417e-a635-46df7627d279",
  "queryResult": {
    "queryText": "bourses",
    "parameters": {
      "type": "Bourses",
      "school": "",
      "campus": ""
    },
    "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
    "fulfillmentText": "Voici les Bourses disponibles pour IDRAC Paris",
    "fulfillmentMessages": [
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            "Voici les Bourses disponibles pour IDRAC Paris"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            "Vous pouvez me demander des détails sur celles qui vous intéressent"
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "outputContexts": [
      {
        "name": "projects/hep-playground/agent/sessions/f69b9423-25d0-bc30-bfff-5f71da18f62d/contexts/school_campus_set",
        "lifespanCount": 249,
        "parameters": {
          "school.original": "",
          "type": "Bourses",
          "school": "",
          "type.original": "bourses",
          "campus.original": "",
          "campus": ""
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "projects/hep-playground/agent/sessions/f69b9423-25d0-bc30-bfff-5f71da18f62d/contexts/awaiting_solution_id",
        "lifespanCount": 1,
        "parameters": {
          "school.original": "",
          "type": "Bourses",
          "school": "",
          "campus.original": "",
          "type.original": "bourses",
          "campus": ""
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "projects/hep-playground/agent/sessions/f69b9423-25d0-bc30-bfff-5f71da18f62d/contexts/awaiting_campus",
        "lifespanCount": 1,
        "parameters": {
          "type": "Bourses",
          "school": "",
          "campus.original": "",
          "type.original": "bourses",
          "campus": "",
          "school.original": ""
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "projects/hep-playground/agent/sessions/f69b9423-25d0-bc30-bfff-5f71da18f62d/contexts/current_session",
        "lifespanCount": 250,
        "parameters": {
          "type": "Bourses",
          "school": "",
          "campus.original": "",
          "type.original": "bourses",
          "campus": "",
          "school.original": ""
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "projects/hep-playground/agent/sessions/f69b9423-25d0-bc30-bfff-5f71da18f62d/contexts/type_set",
        "lifespanCount": 15,
        "parameters": {
          "type": "Bourses",
          "school": "",
          "campus.original": "",
          "type.original": "bourses",
          "campus": "",
          "school.original": ""
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "projects/hep-playground/agent/sessions/f69b9423-25d0-bc30-bfff-5f71da18f62d/contexts/school_set",
        "lifespanCount": 23,
        "parameters": {
          "type": "Bourses",
          "school": "",
          "campus.original": "",
          "type.original": "bourses",
          "campus": "",
          "school.original": ""
        }
      }
    ],
    "intent": {
      "name": "projects/hep-playground/agent/intents/e3236893-676e-4e53-8c87-5b1aa974411e",
      "displayName": "UserSetsType"
    },
    "intentDetectionConfidence": 1,
    "languageCode": "fr"
  }
}
```

I don't understand why the same keys are repeated over and over in every contexts, it doesn't make sense.

We tried to put a `current_session` as output of every intent, hoping that it would keep the context alive somehow (following this guide: https://miningbusinessdata.com/better-dialogflow-bots-part-4-session-variables/)

More of the bot's configuration:

[image]
[image]

Comment: That does seem odd. Can you also show what the `UserSetsType` intent looks like?

Comment: @Prisoner I just added a few screenshots at https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1m7wHRD2nns4zHPlQ1QjbXOjalmfjCgPZ

Comment: Also, webhook is enabled but disabling it doesn't change the behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your `UserSetsType` Intent has all three parameters defined. The `school` and `campus` parameters are empty strings if the user doesn't say anything that would fill them, and most of your responses don't include a way for them to be filled.

All Contexts active (both specified in the GUI and defined by you) capture the parameters that are defined for the Intents that are triggered, even if they are not filled by the user. They're filled with the empty string, to indicate they weren't specifically filled Even if they previously had values, indicating that you're attempting to get the value from a particular Intent will replace them with the empty string, indicating you didn't get them from *that* Intent.

So even if `school` and `campus` were set in a previous Intent. The fact that you specified them in the `UserSetsType` Intent means that those values will be replaced with whatever matched for *that* Intent, and those new values will be put in the `current_session` Context.

While you are on the right track to store the accumulated state in a Context, if you have parameters that may be specified by multiple Intents, then you should be adding them to that session Context under a different parameter name that will be non-conflicting. (So you might map `school` to `savedSchool`.)

Comment: Actually, the 3 input parameters are supposed to be already stored in the context. They come from previous intents that aren't shown in the screenshots. I basically get the `school` in the intent A, then the `campus` in the intent B, then another variable in intent C and finally I arrive at the intent `UserSetsType`, where I lose all previous context (despite the fact everything is properly filled in the intent C. So I somehow manage to keep a proper context from A to C, then lose it.
Would you rather use a webhook fullfilment output context instead of doing this from the GUI?

Comment: I've hopefully clarified my answer, but also corrected it.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much for your help, I finally figured out how to fix it. Deleting the useless rows in "Actions and parameters" fixed it. Also, I removed the output contexts `school_set` and `school_campus_set` since they're not useful, if I understand you correctly, no need to specify them in each intents. _(may be wrong about that, but since we set initial lifespan to 250... well, maybe I should add them back actually. No need for such a high value, but refreshing them in each intent is probably the right way, since they must be kept for the whole session.)_